# Error You attempted to use a firebase module that's not installed on your Android project

Tags: android, react-native, expo, firebase-cloud-messaging, react-native-firebase

I'm trying to add notification to my expo cli project so I choosed react native firebase notification. and I had this error :

```
    useEffect(() => {
       // Assume a message-notification contains a "type" property in the data payload of the screen to open
    
       messaging().onNotificationOpenedApp(remoteMessage => {
         console.log(
           'Notification caused app to open from background state:',
           remoteMessage.notification,
         );
         
       });
    
       // Check whether an initial notification is available
       messaging()
         .getInitialNotification()
         .then(remoteMessage => {
           if (remoteMessage) {
             console.log(
               'Notification caused app to open from quit state:',
               remoteMessage.notification,
             );
             setInitialRoute(remoteMessage.data.type); // e.g. "Settings"
           }
           setLoading(false);
         });
     }, []);

 if (loading) {
   return null;
 }
```

package.json:

```
 "@react-native-firebase/app": "^15.3.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/crashlytics": "^15.3.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^15.3.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/perf": "^15.3.0",
```

app.json:

```
"android": {
 "googleServicesFile": "./google-services.json"
}
      "plugins": [
          [
            "@react-native-firebase/app",        
            "@react-native-firebase/messaging"
                  ]
```

Console :

> Error: You attempted to use a firebase module that's not installed on
> your Android project by calling firebase.app().
>
> Ensure you have:
>
> 1. imported the
>    'io.invertase.firebase.app.ReactNativeFirebaseAppPackage' module in
>    your 'MainApplication.java' file.
> 2. Added the 'new ReactNativeFirebaseAppPackage()' line inside of the
>    RN 'getPackages()' method list.
>
> See http://invertase.link/android for full setup instructions.

Comment: the same issue here.

Comment: did u solved it? still facing this issue

Comment: yes, in my case i had to check the package name everywhere, looks like in firebase i used another package name.. ))))

Comment: where did you change the package name?